# iOS7 Using own tags for the purchased music

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, ios

I decided to post because I have a problem. Unfortunately iOS7 handles the tags of purchased music differently than iOS6 did.

My problem is, that I often don't like the original tags from the iTunes store because they are so inconsistent . So I change them in iTunes on my Mac. Everything seems to be okay until I don't sync my music with my iOS7 devices, my iPhone and iPad and I don't check them on my device. Somehow iOS7 reverts the tags for some of music back to their original. I check my devices' content in iTunes as well and iTunes shows my tags correctly but there is also a downloadable file in silver which has the original tags.

I've already tried different things to get rid of the original tags, deleted the content on my devices, synced automatically and manually as well, turned off the option to show all my music on my device but I'm still unable to list my tags instead of the original ones. The strange part is, that my tags are visible for some older purchases only.

Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue too.  I read on another site to do the following:

1. Have the song/album/artist labeled how you want it in iTunes.
2. Sign out of iTunes on your phone/device (settings, iTunes, Apple ID, sign out)
3. Swipe left on the incorrectly labeled/tagged song within the music app on your phone/device and delete it.
4. Connect phone/device to iTunes and sync.
5. After sync is finished you can sign back in to your Apple ID on the phone/device.

I hope this helps cause it works for me. Surely Apple will fix this because it is annoying to have to keep doing this everytime just to have your music labeled how you want it labeled.